# Entidade HTML aparecendo em "continuar esta discussão no bate papo"

Tags: bug, status-pronto, localização

[Aparece](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37603/navega%C3%A7%C3%A3o-sem-refresh#comment73021_37603) como `discuss&#227;o`:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: vamos brasofilo :D

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18079/discussion-between-jorge-b-and-brasofilo).

Comment: apareceu a margarida!